# RollupJS library React Hook Error useState

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I'm bulding a lib that allow to export react components to a nextjs application, at first time it works very well but when I started to check react hooks on that library it trigger a invalid hook error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

In order to solve issues like that on webpack and microbundle, I was using npm link for development, cause this error happen on production build, that was my reference https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react

This strategy don't work on rollup stack, I tried to link react and do some configs and nothing is working

that's my rollup.config.js

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'

import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'

import styles from "rollup-plugin-styles";

const input = 'src/index.js'
const output = 'dist/index'


export default [
  {
    input: input,
    external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    output: {
      file: `${output}.modern.js`,
      format: 'es',
    },
    plugins: [
      external('./package.json'),
      resolve(),
      commonjs({
        include: ['node_modules/**'],
      }),
      babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**'
      }),
      styles(),
      terser()
    ],
  },
]
```

An that's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.17",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.modern.js",
  "umd:main": "dist/index.umd.js",
  "source": "src/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "rollup -c --environment BUILD:production",
    "watch": "rollup -c --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "@webpack-cli/init": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "microbundle-crl": "^0.13.11",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rollup": "^2.32.1",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^3.1.8",
    "rollup-plugin-sass": "^1.2.2",
    "rollup-plugin-scss": "^2.6.1",
    "rollup-plugin-styles": "^3.11.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^6.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^6.0.4",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.4",
    "source-map-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "static-site-generator-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0"
  }
}
```

When I change my nextjs application on dev mode removing a test useState component it works, but if I reload the page or load directly with a useState component rendered it will trigger a react hook error :(

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: @JeremyCorbello , I don't remember, at the end I choose the git submodule strategy for the project, it works well, but it gives some headaches with submodule issues, you can try to use Lerna instead of rollup

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for my case.

It's necessary peerDependencies setting on the package.json file.

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
},
```

So you try dependencies to peerDependencies.

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
  "file-loader": "^6.2.0"
},
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: can be added in comment section of the question